# Conditional Loottables for Minecraft 1.18.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to create conditional loot tables based on an item? I'm trying to recreate the survival games with guns experience I played long ago on an old server and am trying to set up the system that spawns loot in all the chests using loot tables.

This is what I'm trying to achieve, a chest would spawn with the following:

- Random Ammo type and count
- One random gun that supports that ammo type
- Other items (potions, armor, etc.)

So the idea is that the chest would first roll a random ammo type, but would then roll a random gun for that specific ammo type. I'm using https://misode.github.io/loot-table/, and have all of the weapons and ammo in separate loot tables. I thought I could use set_loot_table function for each ammo type and assign it the compatible guns, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm a noob regarding JSON, so I won't be able to implement pseudo code anyone has, but I'll try my best. For anyone who's wondering, I'm talking about the Timeless and Classics gun mod.